# normalization transitive dependencies

Tags: sql, relational-database, database-normalization

I need help with normalization. I am having trouble understanding how to complete the 3NF on my database project. Here is the 
**1NF**

*Normalized Table*

```
Donut ID(PK)
Donut Name
Description
Unit Price
Donut Order ID
Qty
CustomerID
Last Name
First Name 
Last Name 
Street Address
Apt
City
State
Zip
Home Phone
Mobile Phone
Other Phone
Order Date 
Special Notes
```

**2NF**
*Donut Table*

```
DonutID (PK)
Donut Name
Description
Unit Price
```

*Sales Order Table*

```
Sales OrderID (PK)
CustomerID
Last Name
First Name 
Last Name 
Street Address
Apt
City
State
Zip
Home Phone
Mobile Phone
Other Phone
Order Date
Special Notes
```

*Sales Order Line Item Table*

```
Sales Order (PK)(FK)
Dount ID (PK)(FK)
Qty
```

My problem is getting rid of the transitive dependencies in 3NF. What attribute would I use in my fourth table so nothing is redundant or depending on eachother without the primary key? Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `Sales Order` table has a transitive dependency on the customer's name and address.  If you look closely, you will see that each order will include the full address and name information for a given customer, even though that information probably isn't changing from one order to the next.  To remedy this, you can move this information to a new `Customer` table which would have these fields:

*Customer Table*

```
CustomerID (PK)
Last Name
First Name 
Last Name 
Street Address
Apt
City
State
Zip
Home Phone
Mobile Phone
Other Phone
```

The `Sales Order` table would then become:

*Sales Order Table*

```
Sales OrderID (PK)
Order Date
CustomerID (FK)
Special Notes
```

Note that the order date can remain in the `Sales Order` table because conceptually it represents a timestamp when each order occurred, unique to that particular order.

Comment: Oh wow thank you that makes total sense! Except I forgot to put in the Order Date in the 2NF. Let me edit that, pardon me, I new to programming.

Comment: Seriously I could kiss you right now!! I've been racking my brain for hours on this.